# On Shilov Boundary of Bounded Holomorphic Functions

Tags: complex-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras, holomorphic-functions, several-complex-variables

Let $H^\infty (\mathbb{B}_n)$ be the space of all bounded holomorphic functions from the open unit ball $\mathbb{B}_n$ of $\mathbb{C}^n$ $(n\geq 1)$ to $\mathbb{C}$. It is a Banach algebra. Let $\mathscr{M}_n$ be the maximal ideal space of $H^\infty (\mathbb{B}_n)$. Let $\Delta = \{\phi_z: z\in \mathbb{B}_n\}$ be the evaluation functionals in $\mathscr{M}_n$.

The Shilov boundary is the smallest closed subset of $\mathscr{M}_n$ on which every element of the Gelfand transform of $H^\infty (\mathbb{B}_n)$ attains its supremum.

My question is if $\mathscr{M}_n - \Delta$ is in the Shilov boundary of the Banach algebra $H^\infty (\mathbb{B}_n)$.

Thanks.

Comment: Was this an exercise that someone expects you to be able to do, or iis it your own question? I'm a few decades behind the state of the art here, but my guess is it's a hard question. Do you even know the answer for $n=1$? Could be better for MathOverflow...

Comment: While studying the Shilov boundary, I came across this problem. It is my own question. I don't even know the answer for $n=1$.