How to prove $\widehat{H^{\infty}}$ is a uniform algebra?
Let $T$ be a unit circle. I have been stuck while reading some article regarding the algebra $H^{\infty}=\{f:f\text{ is bounded analytic function on unit disc}\}$. Now who are familiar with the theory of Hardy Space they must know that $H^{\infty}\subseteq L^{\infty}(T)$. Now, condider the Gelfand transform ^$:L^{\infty}(T)\to C(Y)$ where $Y$ is a maximal ideal space of $L^{\infty}(T)$. This map is clearly a isometric isomorphism which is very standard in the existing literature on $C*$ Algebra. Now, consider the image of $H^{\infty}$ under this map denoted by $\widehat{H^{\infty}}$. Now this article claims that $\widehat{H^{\infty}}$ is a uniform algebra. How to prove it? Of course the statement in this paper is given for multiply connected domain. So, I want to know how to do it for disc then possibly got a way for multiply connected domain. If there is any reference for it where the answer is given for the case of both type of domain please mention it thanks.

@Anindya Biswas I have seen a post related to these topics. The post is https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2748760/on-shilov-boundary-of-bounded-holomorphic-functions. Can you please tell me any reference or anything related to my post if possible.

@Pelota I amlo tagging you since you replied to this post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2748760/on-shilov-boundary-of-bounded-holomorphic-functions, seems you might know something regarding these research topics.

Maybe you can try the book "Uniform algebras" by T.W. Gamelin

If I’m not mistaken, for any $f \in L^\infty(T)$, there exists $g, h \in H^\infty$ s.t. $f = g + \bar{h}$. Since $L^\infty(T) = C(Y)$ separates points, the result follows.

@Jordi yes the first thing I have done that I looked into the book mentioned by you but did not get any thing. I am stuck at it since many days.

@DavidGao for $\partial D$ where $D$ is a multiply connected domain?

@Ravi For $D$ being the unit disk at least. Admittedly I don’t know enough about Hardy spaces to be sure about the general case.
